# Can I use 10A multimeter to test 445 watts solar panel

Tags: multimeter, voltage-measurement, amperage, solar-energy

I want to know if I can use a cheap multimeter, model DT-830D, which has a maximum current rating of 10A to test voltage and amperage of a 445 watt solar panel with the following characteristics:

```
Module System Voltage (v) 1500
Open Circuit Voltage - Voc (V) 49.35
Short Circuit Current - Isc (A) 11.47
Maximum Power Voltage - Vmpp (V) 41.28
Maximum Power Current - Impp (A) 10.79
```

[image]

Comment: Boarderline. It can probably take 20 % overcurrent for a short amount of time. Get a current clamp?

Comment: Without risk to your multimeter, only on a cloudy day. The 10 A is unfused; the multimeter may survive if you're quick, it may fry.

Comment: What I would probably do to test that panel is get a 4.7 Ohm power resistor. Connect the resistor to the panel with the ammeter in series. That will keep current less than 10 Amps. Get the type of resistor that can handle 500 Watts for a few seconds. Do your measurement quickly then disconnect the resistor before it overheats.

Comment: @mkeith   Sense resistor is a great idea.   But unsure of the 'in series' part.  Did you mean 'in parallel'??    One way to do this every easily is a 50W 10 ohm resistor shorted across the panel, and read the VOLTAGE on it.   Using 10 ohms makes the math easy...   1V measured = 0.1A being driven.   1 ohm resistor would be 1:1 for math (1V=1A), but would require a 500W resistor....

Comment: @KyleB I would imagine that he wants to measure the current delivered to the load, which would require a low resistance shunt. At the maximum ratings shown the load would be just under 4 ohms, so putting a 10 ohm resistor in series isn't going to work. A 0.01 ohm shunt would give you 10mV per amp and at 10A would only dissipate 1W.

Comment: @GodJihyo ^^^^ That'll work !!!!     You're right, he probably does want this "in situ"....  So I rescind my initial resistor suggestion, but not the concept.    $$$$  We actually have dozens & dozens of exactly that kind of shunt at work .... They're all labeled "50mV/50A", which is basically what you just described except a different multiplier (they are indeed labeled in a convoluted manner --- should just say "0.001 ohm".....).    $$$$   i.e.     https://www.ebay.com/itm/165175173366?hash=item26753520f6:g:KRwAAOSw2rlhiu2z $$$$

Comment: @KyleB Yes, shunt value is basically a trade off between resolution and how much voltage drop and error you can tolerate. The lower the resistance, the more accurate, but also the lower a voltage you're trying to read on the meter.

Comment: Well, my idea was to use the 4.7 Ohm resistor as the load. Then you can measure either the current through the resistor (Ammeter in series) or the voltage across the resistor (Voltmeter in parallel) and use either I^2 * R or V^2 / R to calculate power, since R is known. I am assuming the idea here is just to test the panel, and testing it somewhere in the vicinity of VMPP is probably all that is needed.

Answer (score 3):

You will only see maximum output with the sun directly overhead on a cloudless day. With less sun, the percent available current will drop more than the available voltage.

It would be nice to have a load that would test at the maximum power point. 41.28 V / 10.79 A = 3.8 ohms. The easiest load to find would be some 12-volt incandescent automotive light bulbs. If you have several that are identical connected in parallel, you could measure the current in just one of them and get a reasonably accurate value of the total current by multiplying the meter reading by the number of bulbs.

I would hesitate to connect a cheap meter to read more than 80% of rated current for more than a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I have a multimeter that looks the same as yours. I tested it measuring 1 A on the 10 A range. The internal shunt dropped 0.01 V, which is good (corresponds to 0.1 V at 10 A), but the leads dropped a staggering 0.45 V each. I cut into one of them and this is what I found:-

[image]

The wire diameter measured ~0.25 mm, corresponding to 30AWG. This has a 'chassis wiring' rating of only 0.86 A. At 10 A these leads would drop ~9 V (4.5 V each) and dissipate ~90 W (45 W each). After 5 seconds they would become uncomfortably hot. 10 seconds would probably be enough to melt them.

The meter itself should easily be able to handle 10 A for longer than 10 seconds, but the leads won't. To measure this level of current you should make your own leads with thick wire (16AWG or fatter) and high quality short banana plugs. If you have to use the original meter leads then only connect it for a few seconds and remember that there will be a large voltage drop across the meter.

Comment: Well, hopefully people aren't using those probes in ammeter mode. I usually put in some other type of cable when measuring amps (not the sharp probes). But it is kind of alarming how cheapo those wires look!

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to know if I can use cheap multimeter model DT-830D witch has
> max 10A to test voltage and amperage of 445 watts solar panel with the
> following characteristics:*

`Module System Voltage (v) 1500`

[image]

I think you can make your own mind up on this!

Comment: Well, if the OP is only testing one panel that doesn't matter. And just because the panel has a 1500 V system voltage rating doesn't mean it is operated in a 1500 V system anyway. My panels are rated for 1000 V or something, but my system only delivers around 300 V.

Comment: How would that number help? Solar cell outputs are DC, not AC, the data sheet says the maximum output voltage is about 50 volts. So how does 750 VAC/1000 VDC apply?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast it says 1000 volts DC and who is to say that he isn't testing a whole bunch of them (best to be safe and inform the user or, maybe let Darwin have his wicked way)

Comment: Side note: I'd keep a cheap-as-chips meter like this away from 1000V at all times. Hell, I wouldn't use it on mains. They usually have barely any safety features; any problem on a low-impedance, high-voltage source, and you risk physical injury.

Comment: "Cheap as chips" is a great expression that I had not heard before. I assume that it is a reference to to potato types of chips. It also occurred to me that it could refer to the less widely known cow chips.

Comment: @Andyaka - Well, he does say, "test voltage and amperage of a 445 watt solar panel", rather than an array.

Comment: But he says 1500 volts system voltage.

Comment: Well, my assumption was that the OP was just re-typing all the specifications of the panel. Every panel I have ever seen has a maximum system voltage as part of the specification. Sometimes there are two different voltages for two different regulatory agencies. But that is an assumption on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a 0.1 ohm resistor, put it in series with your 10 amps. Set your meter to 2000mV scale (2 volts scale) and touch the probes to each side of the resistor. If you read 2volts, the current, by ohms law, will be 20 amps.  Hopefully that doesn't happen. But,
At 1000mV, you'll have 10amps.
At 500 mV you'll have 5 amps
At 10 mV, you'll have 1 amp.

Easy, cheap and safe. Also, the most you will interfere with your circuit is a half-volt drop to the load if you are producing 10 amps.

Make sure you select a resistor that is rated well more than 10 amps x 1 volt = 10 watts. A 20 watt "sand bar" resistor should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really recommend measuring the short circuit current of a solar panel by shorting it with an ammeter. My preferred way to test them is by connecting them with an appropriate load resistor. You can get a rough idea of the resistor value using Ohm's law:

V = I * R

Solve for R and use Vmpp and Impp in the equation.

Rload = Vmpp / Impp

I like to use a resistor a bit larger than that. In order to produce rated maximum power, the panel must be at 25 C and the incident light must be 1000 W / m^2 (full sun aimed directly at panel). Since the panel will likely be hotter than 25 C, the actual voltage will be lower than the listed Vmpp. So that is why I use a slightly larger resistor.

Since you know the resistor value, you don't have to measure the current. Just measure the voltage across the resistor. Then you can calculate the current and power in the resistor. You will have to use some judgement to determine if the panel is good. In full hot sun, you may see something like 80 percent of rated power. If the angle is not direct, less. Clouds will drastically reduce power (you really need a nice sunny day).

For such a big panel you will need a fairly large resistor, and it will probably heat up pretty quickly. So be prepared to make your measurement quickly, then disconnect the resistor promptly. There are some resistors that can withstand very high overloads for a short time. So you may be able to just buy a 100 W resistor for this (but make sure to read the datasheet carefully).